# How to store data with nodejs outside of the project folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

I am using ExpressJs and i want to save my files outside of the project like this.
[image]

im using this code for upload and its ok
[image]

my files uploaded correctly but i can not show them in the app cause route will be like this

http://localhost:8000/../../fileArchive/1661839542935/name.jpg

nut when i set this to src of an image, the src doesnt show my image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `express` is trying to protect your project files from getting exposed on a malicious request. By default you cant access any of the files in your project or other directories. You can define a directory that can be accessed using the `express.static` method.

This will define a directory as a static directory which can be accessed (see [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)). After you added this you can also drop the any path in your URL. Express will check for any files matching the name in one of your static directories.

```
// This would allow the user to access the files in that directory
// ../fileArchive will be considered as the fileRoot e.g. localhost:8000/test.txt would look for a test.txt file in ../fileArchive
app.use(express.static('../fileArchive'));

// if you want to keep fileArchive as part of the url you can do that like so 
// however I would recommend to exclude the `..` to keep the url readable and also the exact file path on the server should not concern the user just where he can find it
app.use('/fileArchive', express.static('../fileArchive'))
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I add this line of code but still dont get this image 
 src={
               'http://localhost:8000/../fileArchive/1661839542935/name.jpg'
              }

Comment: update. The way you mention worked. so thanks for that. Just one thing is needed and you can edit your answer and mention it to be useful. when you set a directory with express.static, you dont need to add the directory name. So i should use 'localhost:8000/../1661839542935/name.jpg' not 'localhost:8000/../fileArchive/1661839542935/name.jpg'